# UIStackView not displaying

Tags: swift, layout, uistackview

In my viewController `viewDidLoad` method I have:

```
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    stackView.axis = .Vertical
    self.view.addSubview(stackView)

    for _ in 1..<100{
        let vw = UIButton(type: .System)
        vw.setTitle("Button", forState: .Normal)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(vw)
    }
```

but when I compile I only get a totally white screen.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're adding the stack view to the parent view, but you're not telling the parent view how to lay the stack view out. If you're using constraint based layout, you need to pin the stack view to some of the edges of the parent view:

```
view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView, Attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView, Attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView, Attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
```

This will pin the stack view to the top, leading and trailing edges of the view.

The other approach would be to use Interface Builder to set up the constraints, as they are pretty verbose to manage in code.

Comment: It seems to work if I only add stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

Comment: That may work of you have a very simple layout, but if you have any other subviews that aren't managed by the stack view, or if the default layout isn't what you want, you may need to provide further info through constraints.

Answer (score 2):

You have add constraints or set frame for your stack view. Please check modified code below :

```
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    stackView.axis = .Vertical
    stackView.distribution = .FillEqually

    for i in 1..<100{
        let vw = UIButton(type: .System)
        vw.setTitle("Button\(i)", forState: .Normal)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(vw)
    }

    self.view.addSubview(stackView)
    stackView.frame = self.view.bounds
```

Comment: It seems it works if I only add stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

Comment: you MUST turn off translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints